# Django AttributeError: form object has no attribute x

Tags: python, django

I see many people have already encountered this error, but what I'm trying to do is specific and the answers to those other questions don't help me.
I'm new to Django and I'm trying to make a form with first name, last name, email and password fields, and after the form is submitted, I want all of those to be written in a file. I do not have a User object, and I'm not actually trying to make a sign-in page, I just want to see how I can write stuff to a txt file.

So, I did this, in urls.py:

```
url(r'^file/$', views.employee, name='employee')
```

Then in views.py:

```
def employee(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            with open('employee.txt', 'w') as f:
                myfile = File(f)
                myfile.write('%s ... %s ... %s ... %s ' % form.first_name % form.last_name % form.email % form.password)
        return render(request, 'blog/employee_thanks.html')
    else:
        form = EmployeeForm
    return render(request, 'blog/employee.html', {'form': form})
```

so then I have an EmployeeForm in forms.py:

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

and the relevant html files are:
employee.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Employee Sign-in</h1>
<h3>Please sign in with your Credentials</h3>

<form method="post" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

and employee_thanks.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <h1>Thank you for signing in!</h1>

    <h3>You will get an email with questions soon.</h3>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

And finally, the error in question:

> AttributeError at /file/
>   'EmployeeForm' object has no attribute 'first_name'
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/file/
>   Django Version: 1.10
>   Exception Type: AttributeError
>   Exception Value:
>   'EmployeeForm' object has no attribute 'first_name'

I'm guessing the problem is somewhere between forms.py and views.py, but I have no idea what it could be.
Since I do this as a hobby, please don't be too harsh if the question is dumb.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form` object instance would not have the attributes `first_name`, `last_name`, etc as they are attributes of the underlying object instance.

Instead, you can access the first_name like this:

```
form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
```

You can read more on the [django forms and accessing attributes in this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-form-class)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors in your code.

The first is that the form fields are not attributes of the `Form` instance. Following validation with `form.is_valid()` you can access the fields using the `form.cleaned_data` dictionary, e.g.

```
form.cleaned_data['first_name']
```

or, more safely:

```
form.cleaned_data.get('first_name', '')
```

which will return an empty string instead of raising an exception if the field is not present in the form.

---

The second error is that the string formatting syntax is wrong:

```
myfile.write('%s ... %s ... %s ... %s ' % form.first_name % form.last_name % form.email % form.password)
```

should be:

```
myfile.write('%s ... %s ... %s ... %s ' % (form.cleaned_data['first_name'], form.cleaned_data['last_name'], form.cleaned_data['email'], form.cleaned_data['password']))
```

that is a tuple of the values to be substituted into the string should be used. But it can be simplified by passing the dictionary like this:

```
myfile.write('%(first_name)s ... %(last_name)s ... %(email)s ... %(password)s' % form.cleaned_data)
```

Better yet, use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which is now the preferred way:

```
myfile.write('{first_name} ... {last_name} ... {email} ... {password} '.format(**form.cleaned_data))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very insightful. 
I have a followup question: it appears that when I submit the form twice, the second input overwrites the first one in the .txt file. Am I supposed to use something other that "w" in the line: with open('employee.txt', 'w') as f ?

Update: should have used "a" as "append". Leaving this just in case somebody else needs it, and also to show my appreciation.

Comment: @MiodragNisevic: that's right, use `'a'` because `'w'` overwrites the file. You might want to add a new line to the end of each write so that the fields for each form submission appear on a single line.